# Find the equation of a plane that passes through $3$ points

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an equation of the plane that passes through the points $A(0, 1, 0)$, $B(1, 0, 0)$ and $C(0, 0, 1)$.

Comment: Have you covered vectors yet?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The equation of a plane can be expressed as $ax+by+cz=d$  Since the plane goes through $(1,0,0)$, $a=d$.  Use the other two points in the same way to get the equation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The sum of the $x$-coordinate, $y$-coordinate, and $z$-coordinate for each of those points is $1$.

Now, turn that into an equation.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies. I view the question wrongly.

Find the vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$:

$\vec{AB}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right)$

$\vec{BC}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
-1\\
\end{array}
\right)$

Take the cross product and it will be the normal of the plane.

Normal $n=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right)$

The equation of the plane will be:

$\mathbb{r}\cdot\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right)=1$
or $x+y+z=1$

Answer (score 0):

I would say

Sectional plane equation:  $\frac{x}{p}+\frac{y}{q}+\frac{z}{r}=1$

In this example p = q = r = 1 --> equation x + y + z =1